# UIScrollView with dynamic number of views and Auto Layout iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiview, uiscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

i am struggling with an UIScrollView in iOS6 using auto layout.
What i am trying to do is setting up a scrollview holding a number of subviews (UIViews). Those subviews are created dynamically in a loop. Now i would like to add my contraints, so that it is working with auto layout.

In viewDidLoad I got this code:

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
CGRect selfBounds = self.view.bounds;
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds);
NSMutableString *constraintBuilding = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"|"];

NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    CGFloat offset = width * i;
    UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(selfBounds, offset, 0)];
    [view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [view1 setBackgroundColor:[colors objectAtIndex:i]];
    [scrollView addSubview:view1];
    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view1(height)]|" options:0 metrics:@{@"height":@(height)} views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1)]];
    [constraintBuilding appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[view%i(width)]",i+1]];
}

NSMutableArray *views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int j = 0; j < scrollView.subviews.count; j++) {
    if (![[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:j] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [views addObject:[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:j]];
    }
}


[constraintBuilding appendString:@"|"];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:constraintBuilding options:0 metrics:@{@"width":@(width*colors.count)} views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(views)]];
```

**the looping works just fine, but i'll get an error on the last line**

```
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:constraintBuilding options:0 metrics:@{@"width":@(width*colors.count)} views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(views)]];
```

constraintBuilding says " |[view1(width)][view2(width)][view3(width)]| "
Actually i dont have a view2 and view 3 but i dont know how to set up the contraint?!

**That is the exception:**

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format:
```

view1 is not a key in the views dictionary. 
|[view1(width)][view2(width)][view3(width)]| 
       ^'

For testing i have 3 objects in my colors array, but later this number will change dynamically.

**Thanks for your help!**

Chris

**EDIT:**

one more thing.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153407/my-uiscrollview-doesnt-work-with-auto-layout-in-ios6) article and it worked just fine. but unfortunately it is not in a loop with a dynamic number of views. :(

AND

I read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2154/_index.html) article from apple. but still i couldnt find my answer.

Comment: Did you get this working, I have a similar issue creating constraints for dynamic amount of views

Answer (score 2):

I think there have you result.
just testing, and flow.

use it FOR loop.

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html

Comment: Have more detail in here.

[CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825189/auto-layout-uiscrollview-with-subviews-with-dynamic-heights)

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

> NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(views)

On this line `views` is an array. This will create a dictionary with a single entry, with a key of `views` as an object of your array.

The views dictionary passed into the visual format method must have an entry for each view variable used in the VFL string.

Instead of building up a mutable array of your views, build up a mutable dictionary, adding in each loop the single-view dictionary made when you create the vertical constraints.

You can then use this completed dictionary in the final visual format method.